# comments and code block

Tags: bug, comments, markdown

if I try to place a comment with following text

```
`\\` and etc
```

it appears as

`\` and etc

without code highlight

instead of

`\\` and etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
``\\`` and etc
```

that is, two backticks, instead.

I have posted an example comment on this answer to demonstrate.

Comment: ``\\`` and other stuff

Comment: why not everything in between two back-ticks is highlighted ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi What do you mean? You only need to use two backticks if you are trying to display an inline code snippet consisting entirely of backslashes. For example, `\`a\b\`` produces `a\b`, but you have to use `\`\`\\\\`\`` to produce ``\\\``.

Comment: Sorry I don't see  the reason of providing double backticks ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi because the ``\`` escapes the ` character